# How to connect to a thermal printer using React

Tags: reactjs, printing, epson

We are trying to connect a thermal printer that is connected via USB to my React web application.

For now, we are taking the printout using the default printing flow by using the `react-to-print` package that triggers the print preview. The HTML that contains the bill (data needs to print) will be shown in the print preview. After that, the print preview will be configured which includes selecting the printer, number of copies, etc.
This works fine for my printer i.e HOIN 58MM (2 Inch) printer but does not work properly for other printers with different paper sizes, e.g. EPSON TM T82 MODEL 385.

We have tried packages such as `react-thermal-printer` and `node-thermal-printer`.
We are unable to utilize the above node packages as it is not working in React.
We also tried this https://github.com/rubenruvalcabac/epson-epos-sdk-react package. The challenge with using this package is that we can connect to the printer using the IP address and we are unable to figure out how to find the IP.

Is there a generic way to connect any thermal printer and take a print out responsively in react web application

Comment: I am also stuck on that problem. if u find any solution, could u share with me. I'd be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With react-to-print

- ComponentToPrint.tsx

  ```
  <style type="text/css" media="print">{"@page { size: 80mm 276mm; }"}
  ```

Your app need ask what thermal printer the user has... you can configure a custom field to user filled with the information, you can't discovered by yourself...

You can create a dynamic string like that

```
`@page { size: ${user.thermalWidth} ${height}; }`
```